# Flip Up Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-cardview, flip, objectanimator

I'm trying to make a flipping animation in Android.
I am using this code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Set alpha to 0 before animation -->
  <objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="0"/>

  <!-- Rotate -->
  <objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="180"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"/>

  <!-- Half-way through the rotation set the alpha to 1 -->
  <objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:duration="1"/>
</set>
```

However, I want it to flip from top to bottom. Something like this:

[image: Flip]

How do I do this?

Comment: try changing the propertyName from android:propertyName="rotationY" to android:propertyName="rotationX"

Comment: @InnocentKithinji Tried. Doesn't help.

Comment: Is this a 2D or a 3D animation? A 2D animation would require a serie of prerendered frames (FrameAnimation). A 3D animation would need to render an object in real time (OpenGL, Rajawaly or whatever).

Comment: @BernoulliGate 2D animation. I want to make the view rotate to make it look like it's flipping

Comment: `I want to make the view rotate` Seriously, to rotate an object like that (on the X axis - same goes for the Z axis), you need to render it. It's totally different from simply rotating it on the Y axis. You can't just rotate a View on an arbitrary **3D** axis (you can only rotate on the Y axis), since you are bound to a **2D** view space. Or, simply re-read my previous comment, where I gave you **2** possible solutions.

Comment: @BernoulliGate Why is rotating the view upward different from rotating it sideways, which I accomplished? Both have an 'effect' of 3D.

Comment: @BernoulliGate I don't need that there should be depth to the View, only that it will 'skew' in a way that makes it look like it's flipping.

Comment: Well, my suggestion is to use a FrameAnimation to display a serie of rendered frames - As an alternative you could use an animated GIF.

Comment: @BernoulliGate But I need to create a premade graphic for this, right? The problem is this is a dynamic view...

Comment: Then I can't really help. This goes beyond my current knowledge. Maybe using OpenGL you'll be able to capture a screenshot of your View, texture a plane (or a cube - or a parallepiped) and do the 3D animation in real-time on the fake View. If you were to try Blender (free and open source 3D program - warning! it causes addiction!!), everything would appear much clearer to your vision.

Comment: @BernoulliGate OK. maybe I'll just stay with the side flip... :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programmatically. Here is the C# from Xamarin. Can't test the Java right now but it will be very similar.

```
ImageView block = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgBlock);
ObjectAnimator blockSpin = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(block, "rotationX", 0, 360);
imageCard.PivotX = 0.5f; //so it spins on center

float scale = metrics.Density;
imageCard.SetCameraDistance(8000*scale);
  /*Set camera distance as required to avoid distortion. 
     Multiplying by scale keeps distance the same across devices. */
blockSpin.SetDuration(500);
blockSpin.Start();
```

Comment: Wow, nice! Although it doesn't solve my problem exactly, since I want that on the other side of the flipped object there will be another view, or at least a white background. This just shows on the other side the same view just rotated. Any ideas how to perfect this?

Comment: Well, I set the rotation to 90 degrees, and it seems to do the work pretty well; The other side isn't visible, and on the Animation end I reveal what's 'underneath'. Thanks!!